# Reuse same form after button click

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I have created a page with some form controls. In the same page I have to regenerate the same form on click of button.

How can I reuse the same form after the button has been clicked?

Comment: please include some code to show your work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FormGroup.reset()` method - [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset) are the official docs.